# Center vertically while ignoring other elements

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, centering

I'm trying to center this burger. I used "grid place-items-center" so it gets centered and "h-screen" in order to let it be centered in the full height.
The problem is that it's not in the center, obviously because of the logo at the top.
how do i ignore this logo and center it anyways?

[The navbar i'm coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbKcy.png)

Greetings, PixelPage

Comment: Make the logo `position:absolute` seems most simple

Comment: It would help to show some code and some effort in order to maximize your chances of getting help.

Comment: Already tried it, but it remvoes the centering of the logo

Comment: Can you put your code in tailwind play and put a link to it in your question please? https://play.tailwindcss.com/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Gabe Of course, here's the link https://play.tailwindcss.com/4aNvwW2Jxi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. The only thing you need to do is add a `w-full` to the parent div of logo (the one with the absolute class).

```
<div class="fixed left-0 h-screen bg-gradient-to-t from-[#07C8F9] to-[#6D8AE4] w-24">
  <div class="w-full absolute grid place-items-center mt-8">
    <img src="/assets/branding/logo-white.png" class="w-12 h-12"></img>
  </div>
  <div class="grid place-items-center h-full">
    <img src="/assets/common/Burger.png" class="w-16 h-16"></img>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Read through this guide, it is invaluable, and I reference it all the time. It should help you figure out how to use grid to place your items: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline or its URL changes.